# Trouble with Embeds on slash commands discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want an embed with a picture on the link to come out of command, but it gives an error, what can I do about it?

```
import discord, asyncio, json, requests, time, datetime, files, random,os
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord_components import Button, ButtonStyle, DiscordComponents, SelectOption, Select
import interactions


bot = interactions.Client("")


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")

@bot.command(name="example",description="example description",)
async def example(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    response = requests.get('some url')
    json_data = response.json()
    url = json_data['url']
    embed = discord.Embed(color = 0xff9900, title = '')
    embed.set_image(url='url')
    await ctx.send(embed = embed)


bot.start()
```

Error:

```
payload = await super().send(content, **kwargs)
TypeError: _Context.send() got an unexpected keyword argument 'embed'
```

how i can fix that?

Answer (score -1):

for embeds, you have to follow the format:

```
embedVar = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
```

Also, discord_components is discontinued, you should use interactions.py. Here is the url for the sample code they provide.
Its essentially the same as discord_components:

https://github.com/interactions-py/library/blob/stable/examples/bot.py

Comment: nevermind guys, discord.py is not discontinued anymore!